# Displaying updated ArrayList items properly within a fragment

Tags: android, eclipse, android-listfragment

basically my problem is this. I am trying to display a list view within a fragment set within the xml file, this list view gets its data from an ArrayList that gets its data from a form I created in another activity using Edit Texts which are put into an ArrayList and passed as a Parcelable Array List to the fragment class.

At the start of the fragment activity there of course are no values stored so I bring up the form activity for data input upon checking that there is no intent stored with the id I specify the passed Parcelable ArrayList as. The problem I have is that whenever I try populate the list view with more than one item (having the first item showing up, returning to the form to add another item in), it seems to only display the one item I add each time and not the items I added previously.

```
public class MasterFragment extends ListFragment {

private DetailFragment ingredDetails;
private ArrayList<Ingrediants> ingredList = new ArrayList<Ingrediants>();
private ArrayList<String> test2 = new ArrayList<String>();


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    if (extras != null) { //If extras are present
        boolean data = extras.getBoolean("ingrediant", true);
            if (data) {//Data present from form, retrieve from ArrayList<Ingrediants> and populate the ArrayList<String>
                    ingredList = getActivity().getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("ingrediant");
                    test2.add(ingredList.get(i).ingrediantName);   
                    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, test2));
            }//END OF IF DATA
    }//END OF IF EXTRAS
    else {//No data found, bring up the FormActivity
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(getActivity(), FormActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent3);
    }//END OF ELSE 
}//END OF onCreate()
```

I think it has something to do with how I am creating the list view and populating it with the ArrayList with the data got from the Parcelable ArrayList intent as it could be recreating the list view each time and only displaying the data supplied to it which in this case will be one item at a time. I've been stuck on this for a while now and was wondering if anyone has any ideas ? Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

The ArrayList you use (test2) to keep the data does not persist. You can either save the ingredients in sqlite db and call all items onCreate in your fragment, or move the test2 to the main activity and populate items before passing it with Intent bundle.

Comment: I'm not using a DB this time round, so I would have to populate the test2 ArrayList within the MainActivity with the data and then pass the test2 ArrayList to the fragment class via an Intent bundle to populate the listView in the onCreate method?

Comment: For some reason I now seem to be getting a runtime error upon the fragment class loading up to display the list after I have submitted the ingrediant information via the form and the MainActivity has assigned it to the string ArrayList(confirmed its been assigned using logs)

Comment: Can u share the error log? Maybe type error if ur fragment is expecting a String than ArrayList.

Comment: Hmm, well for MainActivity i got `ingredList = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("ingrediant"); //Retrieve data, store in ArrayList<Ingrediant>       test2.add(moduleList.get(0).ingrediantName); //Add ingrediant name only to the ArrayList<String> from the ArrayList<Ingrediant>
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("ingrediant_passed", test2); //Store the ArrayList<String> within an intent` to retrieve the data and pass it into the test2 string ArrayList. For recieving it in the fragment class I then use: `test2 = extras.getStringArrayList("assignment_passed");`

Comment: Can you share the runtime error log? the exception you got

Comment: I've had a look at the LogCat and there wasn't anything to do with the runtime exception error, having looked at the Variables within the Debug view, under the e variable within the Android Application it does identify: 
`android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
java.lang.NullPointerException
Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment`